# python 3 linear regression problems

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm doing a simple linear regression using `sklearn` (on python3.7), but the intercept and the fit comand give me the same result.
Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'stud': [1,2,3,4,5,6,4,1,2,1,3],'red':[12000,23000,35000,47000,55000,67000,43000,15000, 25000,15000,31500]})
df
mat = np.matrix(df)
x = mat[:,1]
y = mat[:,0]
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr

lr.fit(x,y)
lr.intercept_
```

This last comand gives me the following result:

```
array([-0.26514558])
```

and every value I put on predict comand gives me the same result

```
lr.predict(5)
lr.predict(5)
array([[-0.26467182]])
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I am not getting same value. Try giving larger values inside predict like 1000 or 25000

Comment: Those are not same values?